# Pandas loop issue

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to apply the loop to select the specific values to use in the equation. I have the following data set

| stock | Demand |
| --- | --- |
| 1585 | -1677 |
| 2305 | 20 |
| 34215 | -38968 |
| 30 | 70 |
| 10967 | -4737 |

I am applying the following code

```
for i in Demand:
    if i > df['Stock'].all():
        Order = Demand
    elif i < 0 :
        Order = df['Stock'] - Demand
```

I want the following list

| Order |
| --- |
| 3262 |
| 23005 |
| 73183 |
| 70 |
| 15704 |

But I am getting the following list

| Order |
| --- |
| 3262 |
| 23005 |
| 73183 |
| **-39** |
| 15704 |

I am unable to figure out what is wrong with the loop I am applying here.
Thank you.

Comment: Why 23005? typo?

Comment: can you post the actual code? that looks like pseudocode. it certainly doesn't result in a dataframe.

Comment: @Corralien : I didn't notice it. It must be a wrong number, I am getting out of the code.  Thank you.

Comment: @Corralien: thank you for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand your logic and fixed errors. Is it what you expect?

```
df['Order'] = np.where(df['Demand'] < 0,
                       df['stock'] - df['Demand'],
                       df[['stock', 'Demand']].max(1))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   stock  Demand  Order
0   1585   -1677   3262
1   2305      20   2305
2  34215  -38968  73183
3     30      70     70
4  10967   -4737  15704
```

Comment: @irfanraorao. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: It did work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To debug the code, try to add `print()` statement after every step to see what the code is doing!

Comment: Hi @Daniele - welcome to StackOverflow! This is a debugging tip, but is not an answer to the question. You don't yet have enough reputation to comment - to get started try to find a question you can answer completely. Check out this guide to [answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Good luck :)